# Hyperlink button to open a file

Tags: forms, ms-access, button, hyperlink

I have a Table (Table1) with a list of PDF files, and its Form (Form Table1).

In "Table1" I have a hyperlink field (PDF) and I want a button in "Form Table1" to open that hyperlink. I tried to select this button, go to Event>On Click>Code Builder and type

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Application.FollowHyperlink PDF, , True
End Sub
```

What is the correct method I should be using to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way would be referencing the pdf file's location by referring to the HyperlinkAddress using some VBA. Put this code on a button or whatever event you please:

```
Private Function Get_Link()
   Me![mybutton].HyperlinkAddress = _
   Nz(DLookup("[filename]", "[my_files_table]","[my_files_table].[id]=" & Me![id]), "")
End Function
```

To update the hyperlink you can refer to the Hyperlink's ID or primary key in a form by firing an event like: `OnCurrent: Get_Link()`

This would retrieve the current ID on your form and use that to get the hyperlink you want.

Reference: [Bytes.com](https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/201539-open-pdf-file-button-access)

Comment: I can't put the pdf file's location on the button's HyperlinkAddress since the address is different for each record.

Comment: You don't need to add the code to that property in the "properties menu." Add that code to a button of some sort.

Comment: ok, I have 99 records and 99 different hyperlinks... can you please explain it better? Thank you

Comment: On your form, you will need to probably make it where it can navigate through each record of hyperlinks. Whatever record the form is on can pass that current ID to this code that's on a button. When you click that button, it should go fetch that record and it's hyperlink.

Comment: Exactly! How can I do it?

Comment: You would have to first go in design view on your form and make the record source the table that you are wanting to use for the hyperlinks